# why rapidjson fails to get this integer value

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

I'm surprised that the following code doesn't work as intended , I remember I had similar json which contained a lot of numbers but I don't know when it stopped working !!!

```
std::string_view jsonStr = "{ \"num\": 1, \"str\": 's' }";
rapidjson::Document doc;
doc.Parse(jsonStr.data());
std::cout << "num : " << doc["num"].GetUint() << std::endl;
```

the output :

```
0
```

if I remove the `str` I get `1` !

Am I making something wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**That is not valid JSON.**

Strings are surrounded by *double* quotes, not single quotes.

Refer to https://json.org for the schema.

Then check for error codes in your JSON parsing library: somewhere it will be telling you this, and you're ignoring it.

`GetUint()` on a non-existent property of a broken document will be returning zero either by default or as part of some "undefined behaviour" in the library; read its documentation to find out which.

Comment: But in my real json I check for `HasParseError` which returns false ! I may paste a reasonable part of it when I get access to it

Comment: Present an actual [mcve] that reproduces the problem, not some made up thing.